# Can unexecuted code cause a segfault?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

Yeah I know that sounds crazy but that is the only way I can describe it at this point. I’m writing a program for a class that mimics a terminal, in that it takes commands as inputs and executes them. (I’ll put some code below) As you will see, the program holds a history of commands historyArgs so that the user can execute recent commands.

Command history is listed when the user performs Ctrl-C. Recent commands are accessed with the command 'r' (for most recent) and r 'x' (where x is matches the first letter of a command in recent history). When I started implementing the 'r' command, I started getting this segfault. I then reverted all my changes and added one line at a time. I found that adding even primitive variable declaration causes a segfault (int temp = 10;) But this is where it gets stranger. I believe the line that causes a segfault (int temp = 10;) is never accessed. I put printf statements and flush the output at the beginning of the if block to see if the block has been entered, but they don't execute.

setup was provided for us. It takes the user input and puts it in char *args[] i.e. input = ls -a -C, args = {"ls", "-a", "-C", NULL, ... NULL}. I marked the line in main that somehow leads to a segfault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 50
static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

#define MAX_LINE 80 /* 80 chars per line, per command, should be enough. */

char *historyArgs[10][MAX_LINE/2 + 1];
int historyCount = 0;
int indexOfLatestCommand = 0;

/* the signal handler function */
void handle_SIGINT() {
    //write(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if(historyCount > 0){
        printf("\n%i command(s), printing most recent:\n", historyCount);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < historyCount && i < 10; i++){
            printf("%i.] %s ", i+1, historyArgs[i][0]);
            //print args
            int j = 1;
            while(historyArgs[i][j] != NULL){
                printf("%s ", historyArgs[i][j]);
                j++;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("\nNo recent commands.\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}

/**
 * setup() reads in the next command line, separating it into distinct tokens
 * using whitespace as delimiters. setup() sets the args parameter as a 
 * null-terminated string.
 */

void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[],int *background)
{
    int length, /* # of characters in the command line */
        i,      /* loop index for accessing inputBuffer array */
        start,  /* index where beginning of next command parameter is */
        ct;     /* index of where to place the next parameter into args[] */

    ct = 0;

    /* read what the user enters on the command line */
    length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, MAX_LINE);  

    start = -1;
    if (length == 0)
        //exit(0);            /* ^d was entered, end of user command stream */
    if (length < 0){
        perror("error reading the command");
    exit(-1);           /* terminate with error code of -1 */
    }

    /* examine every character in the inputBuffer */
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        switch (inputBuffer[i]){
        case ' ':
        case '\t' :               /* argument separators */
            if(start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];    /* set up pointer */
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0'; /* add a null char; make a C string */
            start = -1;
            break;

        case '\n':                 /* should be the final char examined */
            if (start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            args[ct] = NULL; /* no more arguments to this command */
            break;

        case '&':
            *background = 1;
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            break;

        default :             /* some other character */
            if (start == -1)
                start = i;
    }

    }    
    args[ct] = NULL; /* just in case the input line was > 80 */
} 


int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE]; /* buffer to hold the command entered */
    int background;             /* equals 1 if a command is followed by '&' */
    char* args[MAX_LINE/2+1];/* command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */
    int status;

    struct sigaction handler;
    handler.sa_handler = handle_SIGINT; 
    sigaction(SIGINT, &handler, NULL);
    strcpy(buffer,"Caught <ctrl><c>\n");

    while (1){            /* Program terminates normally inside setup */
        background = 0;
        printf("COMMAND->");
        fflush(0);
        setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);       /* get next command */

        //If command wasn't empty
        if(args[0] !=  NULL){
            if(strcmp(args[0], "r") != 0){
                //Copy into history if not a recent call
                for(i = 0; i < MAX_LINE/2+1 && args[i] != NULL; i++){
                    historyArgs[historyCount%10][i] = malloc(strlen(args[i]));
                    strcpy(historyArgs[historyCount%10][i], args[i]);
                }
                indexOfLatestCommand = historyCount%10;
                historyCount++;
            }


            //Create child process
            int pid = fork();

            //In child process
            if(pid == 0){
                if(strcmp(args[0], "r") == 0){
                    //If only "r" was entered, execute most recent command
                    if(args[1] == NULL){
                        printf("Entering recent?\n");
                        fflush(stdout);
                        int temp = 10; //SEGFAULTS HERE IF THIS IS INCLUDED
                        execvp(historyArgs[indexOfLatestCommand][0], &historyArgs[indexOfLatestCommand][0]);
                    }
                    else{
                        //Find in args[1][0] history, run if found
                        for(i = indexOfLatestCommand; i >= 0; i--){
                            if(historyArgs[i][0][0] == args[1][0]){
                                execvp(historyArgs[i][0], &historyArgs[i][0]);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(i == -1){
                            for(i = historyCount > HISTORY_SIZE ? HISTORY_SIZE : historyCount; i > indexOfLatestCommand; i--){
                                if(historyArgs[i][0][0] == args[1][0])
                                execvp(historyArgs[i][0], &historyArgs[i][0]);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else execvp(args[0], &args[0]);
            }
            //In parent process
            else if (pid > 0){
                /*If child isn't a background process,
                 wait for child to terminate*/
                if(background == 0)
                    while(wait(&status) != pid);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Another thing worth mentioning is that declaring a variable in that spot doesn't cause a segfault. Only assigning a value to a new variable does. Reassigning globals in that section also doesn't cause a segfault.

EDIT: What triggers a crash. Commands execute correctly. When you run it, you can type in any command, and that should work. It isn't until I perform Ctrl-C and print out the history that the program segfaults.

Example input:

ls
ls -a
grep
*Ctrl-C*

HEADS UP: if you decide to run this, know that to end the task, you will probably need to use the kill command because I haven't implement "q" to quit.

Comment: Oh man, the undefined behavior in that signal-handler. Have you ever heard of async-safety?

Comment: Here are some things to try: (1) Run the program under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/); this has an excellent chance of revealing that the bug is nowhere near where you think it is.  (2) Turn off all optimizations (`-O0`).  (3) Extract all of the code in the `if (pid == 0) {` block to its own function.

Comment: It's entirely possible, by adding a variable and assigning to it you are changing the layout of the stack (and initializing a portion of it), so if you are accessing it by mistake through a dangling pointer you can get a different result (possibly a segfault). This happens often when incorrectly using a pointer to a local variable of a function that has returned.

Comment: My guess is that you're not null-terminating your `argv` that you pass to `execvp`, and that `execvp` is segfaulting after accessing uninitialized pointers. Always put `NULL` at the end of your argument list.

Comment: We are unlikely to be able to help you any further unless you provide us with a *complete program* that we can compile and run for ourselves and watch crash. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But most importantly: *in signals handlers almost nothing is safe*. There's an extremely short list of syscalls and library functions that you can call in a signal handler. `printf` and in general C library IO functions are *absolutely* prohibited. Ideally a signal handler should just set some flag and return, letting the "regular" program flow take care of the issue later.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: "just set some flag" is a bit unspecific: The flag *has to be* either lock-free atomic or of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: @zwol I just added the setup function, and the code is now complete. Ive never used valgrind but I will try to figure it out

Comment: @sadelbrid Could you also please tell us exactly how you run the program and what you type at it in order to trigger the crash?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any point in trying to debug this program, using a signal handler like that is hopelessly broken by design. You have to learn how to write signal handlers or avoid them altogether if possible. In this particular case, I would forget about signals and instead handle the key combinations directly from the main code path. There's some work to do to handle the tty I'm raw mode, but it's way more flexible (you can use whatever key combination you want) and it's way simpler to wrap your mind around it than around async-safety.

Comment: @zwol Thanks, I just added example input to my post

Comment: @MatteoItalia Unfortunately I'm not writing the signal handler by my choice. We haven't really been taught how to write them correctly either

Comment: @EOF: of course you are right, I was just sketching the situation - before writing a signal handler one should read more detailed documentation than a comment on SO =)

Comment: @EOF I haven't heard of async-safety. We haven't been taught much about signal handlers. I'm guessing I should look into it

Comment: @MatteoItalia Most of the usual concerns with async signal safety don't appear to apply in this case, since the signal handler executes while the main program is blocked on a call to read(); libc isn't in the middle of doing anything sensitive.  (note that setup() does not use stdio for input)

Comment: @sadelbrid Uncomment the call to `exit(0)` inside setup().  Does the problem mysteriously change?  (You may not have realized that commenting it out like that caused the `if (length < 0)` block immediately afterward to become nested into the `if (length == 0)` condition, and therefore that too will never be executed.)

Comment: @zwol: that's when it's normally invocated, but nothing stops the user from pressing Ctrl-C exactly when the main flow is in the `printf` that follow, or `malloc` below, or when he's updating the history. If you want to make safe this approach probably the simplest thing would be to enable/disable the signal handler just around the `read` (and set it to ignored after it). (I'm sorry if I'm being pedantic over a possibly tangential issue, but I've been bit too many times by signal handlers written carelessly by people who didn't know what they were doing)

Comment: `//exit(0);` is a mistake; it means that the following `if (length < 0)` is now a sub-statement of `if (length == 0)` so you actually never test if the read failed

Comment: @M.M  Oops didn't realize that would be nested. I uncomment and commented out the perror and exit line when length < 0. Now the program can be termined with ctrl D

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yeah, I don't mean to suggest that the signal handler is "just fine" or anything, I just strongly suspect it is not the OP's immediate problem and I would hate for their first impression of us to be "they rambled on for ages about something that wasn't even the bug".

Answer (score 2):

Symptoms like you see (unrelated code changes appear to affect the nature of a crash) usually mean that your program caused undefined behaviour earlier.  The nature of the behaviour changes because your program is relying on garbage values it has read or written at some stage.

To debug it, try and remove all sources of undefined behaviour in your program. The most obvious one is the content of your `void handle_SIGINT()` function.  The *only* things you can portably do in a signaler are:

- Set a variable of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`, or other lock-free type, and return
- Do other stuff and call `_Exit`, `abort` or similar.

Especially, you cannot call any library functions as they may not be re-entrant.

For a full specification see section 7.14.1 of the current C Standard. If you are also following some other standard, e.g. POSIX, it may specify some other things which are permitted in a signal handler.

If you do not intend to exit then you must set a flag , and then test that flag from your main "thread" later to see if a signal arose.